# issues with sinon testing azure containerclient.listblobsbyhierarchy

Tags: node.js, typescript, sinon

I have the following rest endpoint code "/files/lookup". This will receive a query parameter folderPath, and will return a list of files with details (including metadata) but not content.
I am including the content of the rest endpoint. This connects to azure blob storage.

```
@get('/files/lookup', { ... })
...
const blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
        this.azureStorageConnectionString,
    );
    const containerClient: ContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
    const filesPropertiesList: FileProps[] = [];
 try {
        for await (const item of containerClient.listBlobsByHierarchy('/', {
            prefix: decodedAzureFolderPath,
            includeMetadata: true,
        })) {
            if (item.kind !== 'prefix') {
                const blobitem: BlobItem = item;
                const blobProperties: BlobProperties = blobitem.properties;
                const blobMetadata: Record<string, string> | undefined = blobitem.metadata;

                const aFileProperties: FileProps = {
                    name: item?.name,
                    uploadedDate:
                        blobProperties.lastModified?.toISOString() ?? blobProperties.createdOn?.toISOString(),
                    size: blobProperties.contentLength,
                    contentType: blobProperties.contentType,
                    metadata: blobMetadata,
                };
                filesPropertiesList.push(aFileProperties);
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.statusCode === 404) {
            throw new HttpErrors.NotFound('Retrieval of list of files has failed');
        }
        throw error;
    } 
   return filesPropertiesList;
```

I am working on sinon test. I am new to sinon. I could not get to effectively use mocks/stubs/etc. to test the endpoint returning a list of files with properties. Couldn't get my head around mocking/stubbing the listBlobsByHierarchy method of the container client

```
describe('GET /files/lookup', () => {
    let blobServiceClientStub: sinon.SinonStubbedInstance<BlobServiceClient>;
    let fromConnectionStringStub: sinon.SinonStub<[string, StoragePipelineOptions?], BlobServiceClient>;
    let containerStub: sinon.SinonStubbedInstance<ContainerClient>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        blobServiceClientStub = sinon.createStubInstance(BlobServiceClient);
        fromConnectionStringStub = sinon
            .stub(BlobServiceClient, 'fromConnectionString')
            .returns((blobServiceClientStub as unknown) as BlobServiceClient);

        containerStub = sinon.createStubInstance(ContainerClient);
        blobServiceClientStub.getContainerClient.returns((containerStub as unknown) as ContainerClient);
    });

    afterEach(async () => {
        fromConnectionStringStub.restore();
    });

    it('lookup for files from storage', async () => {
        /*             let items: PagedAsyncIterableIterator<({ kind: "prefix"; } & BlobPrefix) | ({ kind: "blob"; } & BlobItem), ContainerListBlobHierarchySegmentResponse>;

                    sinon.stub(containerStub, "listBlobsByHierarchy").withArgs('/', { prefix: "myf/entity/172/", includeMetadata: true }).returns(items);
                    const response = await client.get(`/files/lookup?folderpath=myf%2Fentity%2F172%2F`).expect(200); */
    });
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find any ways to mock the return of this method with the same type, I went with type "any". As I am a novice on this, it was really challenging to get my head to do this!

```
it('lookup for files from storage', async () => {
        /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention */
        const obj: any = [
            {
                kind: 'blob',
                name: 'myf/entity/172/0670fdf8-db47-11eb-8d19-0242ac13000.docx',
                properties: {
                    createdOn: new Date('2020-01-03T16:27:32Z'),
                    lastModified: new Date('2020-01-03T16:27:32Z'),
                    contentLength: 11980,
                    contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                },
                metadata: {
                    object_name: 'Testing.docx',
                    category: 'entity',
                    reference: '172',
                    object_id: '0670fdf8-db47-11eb-8d19-0242ac13000',
                },
            },
        ];
        containerStub.listBlobsByHierarchy.returns(obj);

        const actualResponse = await (await client.get('/files/lookup?folderpath=myf/entity/172')).body;
        const expectedResponse: any[] = [ WHATEVER ]
        expect(actualResponse).deepEqual(expectedResponse);
    });
```